# Select distinct values where condition having sum < value

Tags: sql, sum, distinct, having

I have a problem with a SQL query. I need to get a list of all unique [Cod Angajat] field for which the sum of all entries in the column [Timp declarat] is less than 8, with the where clause. Bellow is what I've gotten so far.

In the table I have 3 rows. It returns me the same rows, instead of 1 row, for which all the conditions apply - meaning the one with [Cod Angajat] = 2.

```
|   Cod Angajat  |   Nume   |  Timp declarat  |
---------------------
|  1             |  Ene     | 3               |
|  1             |  Ene     | 5               |
|  2             |  Gigi    | 4               |
```

```sql
select COUNT(DISTINCT [Cod Angajat]), [Cod Angajat], [Nume], [Timp declarat]
FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieVE]
WHERE (sum([Timp declarat] < 8 AND cast(CONVERT(varchar(8), Data, 112) As DateTime) = @data2) and ([Schimb] = '" & ProceseazaSCH(Now()) & "' 
GROUP BY [Nume], [Cod Angajat], [Timp declarat]
HAVING sum([Timp declarat]) < 8
```

Comment: Show table data, current result and expected result.

Comment: You are grouping by [Timp declarat], then the sum aggregation works for rows where all field values are equal. You have to group only by [Cod Angajat] and [Nume].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need one row per `[Cod Angajat]`, then that should be in the `GROUP BY` -- and nothing else:

```
SELECT [Cod Angajat], SUM([Timp declarat]
FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieVE]
WHERE CONVERT(date, Data) = @data2 AND
      ([Schimb] = '" & ProceseazaSCH(Now()) & "'
GROUP BY [Cod Angajat]
HAVING SUM([Timp declarat]) < 8;
```

The rest of the query simplifies as well.  There is no need to convert a date/time to a string to remove the time component.  And aggregation functions don't belong in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

With the query you are grouping by Timp declarat which is why you have duplicates of Cod Angajat in your return set. Since everywhere else in the query is using the Sum of Timp Declarat I would assume the below is what you require:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT [Cod Angajat]), [Cod Angajat], [Nume], SUM([Timp declarat]) as SumTimpDeclarat
FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieVE]
WHERE (sum([Timp declarat] < 8 AND cast(CONVERT(varchar(8), Data, 112) As DateTime) = @data2) and ([Schimb] = '" & ProceseazaSCH(Now()) & "' 
GROUP BY [Nume], [Cod Angajat]
HAVING sum([Timp declarat]) < 8
```

Comment: `code` SELECT [Cod Angajat],sum([Timp declarat]) as TotalOre FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieVE] WHERE cast(CONVERT(varchar(8), Data, 112) As DateTime) = '2016-05-23' And [Schimb] = 'SCH I' GROUP BY [Cod Angajat] HAVING sum([Timp declarat])<8 `code` the working query. tks alot for your valuable input.